# Do I have to fill W9/w4/I9 and state tax form?

Tags: taxes

I just want to know Does a non-US citizen/ non resident working remotely for a US-based company from their home country have to fill W9/W4/I9 and state tax forms?

Comment: As an employee or as a freelancer ?